# Is it possible to hide unused values in a TFS query?

Tags: tfs

I'm in the process of setting up TFS (using the Scrum template) for our company, and was wondering if it's possible and/or recommended to hide some of the unused system values in the query editor. To clarify, when creating a Bug query that filters on State, the dropdown for Value contains all possible values defined by System.State. Since only a subset of those values are actually used by the Scrum process template, I'm worried that it may be confusing for our users.

I've tried removing them from the AllowedValues collection in the WorkItem Field Explorer, but it's readonly (perhaps for good reason).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy to filter this list and it will always contain all values for the field for this collection.